# Different API each a server in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My localhost angular project's api is:
ServerRoot = "api.mylocalhost.com"

But the project must use a different API on server.

I don't want to change adress manually every deploy.

How can i configure it? I need like web.config in .net

Answer (score 0):

If your using a build system like Grunt, Look into ngconstant.  It allows you to define environment specific values depending on the build.

[here is a link to the project](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a configuration file. There's a well known format called INI that you can use. So you'd have one copy locally and one on the server with the information that needs changing.

I've used https://github.com/isaacs/ini previously with some success.